# How can I send a message to another node?

Tags: erlang

I want to implement a simple chat room in which two nodes can send message to each other synchronous. There is not a node that plays a role of server.

Can I use `!` to send a message to another node, if i have the pid of the process on this node by function of `spawn(Node,Module,Fun,Args)`?

Comment: Can I use "!" to send a message to faraway node, if i have the Pid of the process on this node by function of "spawn(Node,Module,Fun,Args)"?

Comment: Yes, sending remote messages is just like sending local ones

Comment: You only need to make sure that all nodes use the same cookie.

Answer (score 23):

You can send to processes at another node just the same you would do with a process local to the same node. The trick is of course you need to have the process id. But you can also send to a process registered at another node by using the tuple {RegisteredName, NodeName}, e.g.

```
register(a, self()), {a, node()} ! foo.
```

will send a message to yourself.The same syntax works across nodes.

A more elaborate example

In the first shell:

```
erl -sname one
Erlang R15B01 (erts-5.9.1) [source] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.9.1  (abort with ^G)
one@grannysmith)1> (one@grannysmith)1> register(hello_server, self()).
(one@grannysmith)2>
true
```

In the second shell:

```
erl -sname two
Erlang R15B01 (erts-5.9.1) [source] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.9.1  (abort with ^G)
two@grannysmith)1> (one@grannysmith)1> {hello_server, 'one@grannysmith'} ! good_day.
good_day
(two@grannysmith)2>
```

And again in the first shell:

```
(one@grannysmith)2> flush().
Shell got good_day
ok
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I just tried this, it worked well. Will you please give me some information like books or websites to master erlang?

Comment: @Despicable.Me http://learnyousomeerlang.com/ is a very good online book on Erlang, there is also a printed version. Otherwise just check on Amazon.