# How do I connect to an Erlang node which uses a short name?

Tags: erlang

When I run `erl -sname foo`, the node name created uses the hostname, rather than "localhost", so it is generated as, for example, `foo@roger-pc`.

I then `register(shell, self())`, and I can send messages to it from another node (`erl -sname bar`) as follows:

```
{shell, 'foo@roger-pc'} ! {hello, world}.
```

But it doesn't work if I use `{shell, foo} ! {knock, knock}`. The message is never received.

How do I connect to an Erlang node on the same PC which is using a short name? Or: how do I derive the "@roger-pc" part of the destination node name? Or: should I just use `erl -name foo@localhost` to register a long name?

Some background: I'm writing a an escript which spawns an `erl` process, and I'd like to be able to send messages from that OS process back to the original script.

Comment: Hey Roger, you probably would check this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16913436/how-can-i-send-a-message-to-another-node

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can specify 'localhost' explicitly for sname.

first shell

```
erl -sname ax@localhost
register(rcvr, self()).
```

second shell

```
erl -sname bx@localhost
net_kernel:connect_node(ax@localhost).
{rcvr, ax@localhost} ! hello.
```

and first shell again

```
(ax@localhost)7> flush().
Shell got hello
ok
```

Comment: Yes, it's a typo: that's the registered name for the process; it must match. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

sname still requires the '@' notation.  You just don't have to input the full uri when sending messages.

```
c:\>erl -sname short
(short@hostname)1> {process, 'short@hostname'} ! Message.

c:\>erl -name short
(short@hostname.more.stuff)1> {process, 'short@hostname.more.stuff'} ! Message.
```

short is not the full name.  sname and name merely decide how much of the rest of the path is required.

Answer (score -2):

> A node is an executing Erlang runtime system which has been given a name, using the command line flag -name (long names) or -sname (short names).

The format of the node name is an atom name@host where name is the name given by the user and host is the full host name if long names are used, or the first part of the host name if short names are used. node() returns the name of the node. Example:

% erl -name dilbert
(dilbert@uab.ericsson.se)1> node().
'dilbert@uab.ericsson.se'

% erl -sname dilbert
(dilbert@uab)1> node().
dilbert@uab

Comment: Doesn't answer the question: "how do I figure out the name that `-sname` actually used when I want to connect to that node?"